# iTunes Connect Error: "This email address is not available for use as an Apple ID."

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-id

When attempting to add a user to iTunes Connect, I get the following error:

[image: Add user iTunes Connect error]

> This email address is not available for use as an Apple ID. You may already have an Apple ID associated with this address. Please try again or sign in using your existing Apple ID.

This is a different error from the one I usually get, which occurs when trying to add a user with an email address already associated with a different iTunes Connect account.

Why is this error occurring?

How do I fix the issue and invite this user to my iTunes Connect account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn’t seem to be programming-related.

Comment: It's an issue that programmers will hit when attempting to send out TestFlight builds. No results out there for this error. Attempting to spread the knowledge.

Comment: Was a solution found? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Ash I have not found a solution.

Comment: Having the same issue. No solution yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Problem**

> The issue that I found was that the email address was being used as an alternate email on an already existing account.

**Solution**

> Remove the alternate email or change it, then you will be able to use the email for an Apple ID.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Exactly our problem.
Really helpful error message, Apple.